# behat & mink in symfony2 : @javascript tag issue

Tags: javascript, symfony, behat, mink

I am facing an issue while trying to use Behat and mink within a symfony project (sf2.4).

**Situation:**

I just started to test behat for symfony2 projects, which looks like awesome. I would also be able to use mink, as my main projects are currently web projects. I therefore follow the tutorial of the official doc: [official doc](http://docs.behat.org/cookbook/behat_and_mink.html#writing-your-first-web-feature)

**Issue:**

While testing "In browser" solution with selenium, I download the jar, start it, and run via another cmd line window:

```
php bin/behat features/search.feature
```

and there comes an error:

```
 [Behat\Testwork\ServiceContainer\Exception\ProcessingException]           
 The @javascript tag cannot be used without enabling a javascript session
```

EDIT: featureContext.php looks like this

```
<?php
#features/FeatureContext.php

use Behat\Behat\Context\SnippetAcceptingContext;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;

use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;

/**
 * Behat context class.
*/
//class FeatureContext implements SnippetAcceptingContext
class FeatureContext extends MinkContext
{
    /**
     * Initializes context.
     *
     * Every scenario gets it's own context object.
     * You can also pass arbitrary arguments to the context constructor through behat.yml.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }
}
```

**Solution:**

I am not too sure about 1) the meaning of this error (javascript session?) nor about 2) how to solve it. I wasn't able to get appropriate documentation on the web about causes and fix.

Any hint much appreciated!

EDIT2:
Once this part was solved either by solving typo in #behat.yml, or by following doc for behat3 see jakub's post, which I was using at the time of this post), I had a second error:

```
Install MinkSelenium2Driver in order to use selenium2 driver.
```

This error was most evidently due to wrong composer setup. Just adding:

```
"behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "*"
```

solves this second issue. and it works!

Kind regards,

Comment: What does your FeatureContext.php file look like? Is it extending the MinkContext without any other modifications?

Comment: Hi scragar, thks for your feedback. I edited my question with the FeatureContext.php content

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to do what the message tells you to do and configure the javascript session ;)

```
default:
  suites:
    first:
      mink_session: default
      mink_javascript_session: selenium2
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url:  'http://example.com'
      sessions:
        default:
          goutte: ~
        selenium2:
          selenium2: ~
```

You're reading the docs from Behat v2 but you're using Behat v3.

Docs for v3 are not on behat.org just yet. For now, read them here: http://behat.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

For MinkExtension go here: https://github.com/Behat/MinkExtension/blob/master/doc/index.rst

Docs should be published to behat.org soon (hopefuly).

Comment: oops. I posted in the same time.Thks. I will have a look at this and come back to you.

Comment: This is quite helpful. I didn't know where to get documentation for Behat v3. I am still facing issue nb 2, but I will have a look in the given link and check if my installation of selenium was v3 compliant